# MySQL - Using COUNT(*) in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, count, aggregation, having

I am trying to accomplish the following in MySQL (see `pseudo` code)

```
SELECT DISTINCT gid
FROM `gd`
WHERE COUNT(*) > 10
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC
```

Is there a way to do this without using a (SELECT...) in the WHERE clause because that would seem like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 348):

try this;

```
select gid
from `gd`
group by gid 
having count(*) > 10
order by lastupdated desc
```

Comment: +1 for having
This is *always* the clause that They Don't Bother To Teach Properly on sql courses or books and knowing about it generally the sign that the coder has progressed beyond novice level.

Comment: What if you are trying to use the COUNT() as part of a boolean OR expression? e.g. `AND ((stock = 1 OR quantity > 0) OR (COUNT(v.id) > 0)`

Comment: I figured it out.. you can add to the HAVING clause like so: `HAVING variations > 0 OR (stock = 1 OR quantity > 0)`

Answer (score 30):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to do... maybe something like

```
SELECT gid, COUNT(*) AS num FROM gd GROUP BY gid HAVING num > 10 ORDER BY lastupdated DESC
```

Comment: MSSQL gives *"invalid column name"* parse error for `num`. +1 anyway for the clean syntax (could be my setup, or ms... ahh well).

Comment: Provide an alias for all columns in the select.

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `gd`
GROUP BY gid
HAVING COUNT(gid) > 10
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC;
```

EDIT (if you just want the gids):

```
SELECT MIN(gid)
FROM `gd`
GROUP BY gid
HAVING COUNT(gid) > 10
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Joe but that returns the COUNT() - I am looking to return all the gid's which have a COUNT(*) more then 10

Comment: There is no need to Min() in there.

Answer (score 21):

Just academic version without having clause:

```
select *
from (
   select gid, count(*) as tmpcount from gd group by gid
) as tmp
where tmpcount > 10;
```

Answer (score 20):

There can't be aggregate functions (Ex. COUNT, MAX, etc.) in A WHERE clause. Hence we use the HAVING clause instead. Therefore the whole query would be similar to this:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value;
```

Answer (score 15):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT gid
FROM `gd`
group by gid
having count(*) > 10
ORDER BY max(lastupdated) DESC
```

Answer (score 10):

> COUNT(*) can only be used with HAVING and must be used after GROUP BY
>   statement Please find the following example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), M_Director.PID FROM Movie
INNER JOIN M_Director ON Movie.MID = M_Director.MID 
GROUP BY M_Director.PID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```

Answer (score 6):

-- searching for weather stations with missing half-hourly records

```
SELECT stationid
FROM weather_data 
WHERE  `Timestamp` LIKE '2011-11-15 %'  AND 
stationid IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `weather_stations`)
GROUP BY stationid 
HAVING COUNT(*) != 48;
```

-- variation of yapiskan with a where .. in .. select

Answer (score 0):

i think you can not add `count()` with `where`. now see why ....

`where` is not same as `having` , `having` means you are working or dealing with group and same work of count , it is also dealing with the whole group ,

now how count it is working as whole group

create a table and enter some id's and then use:

```
select count(*) from table_name
```

you will find the total values means it is indicating some group ! so `where` does added with `count()` ;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT gid
FROM `gd`
GROUP BY gid
HAVING COUNT(gid) > 10
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC;
```