# Updating a field based on a count of records from a different table

Tags: sql, count

I need to set a value to 1 in table where the count for a given role in another table is > 1.

The table cursillo.members has fields memid and hsd.  Table cursillo.teams has fields memid (the link between the two) a field called movement and another called role.

What I am trying to accomplish is something similar to this:

```
update cursillo.members_eligible p, cursillo.teams pp
   set p.hsd=1     
 where p.memid = pp.memid AND (pp.role = 'HSD' OR pp.role = 'SD')
   and pp.movement = 'Cursillo' AND count(pp.role) > 1;
```

or this:

```
update members_eligibile
   set hsd=1 
  from teams 
 where teams.memid=members_eligible.memid 
   and (teams.role = 'HSD' OR teams.role = 'SD')  
   and teams.movement = 'Cursillo' 
   and count(teams.role) > 1;
```

In other words if a given memid has more than one record in the cursillo.teams table where the value of the role is equal to either HSD or SD, then set cursillo.members_eligible.hsd to 1.

I can't figure out to handle the count() part.

Thanks,
Mike Reed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate question:

[MySQL - Using COUNT(*) in the WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301793/mysql-using-count-in-the-where-clause)

Try using the 'having' keyword

Here's the relevant section from the linked answer (in this case, a select statement):

```
select gid
from `gd`
group by gid 
having count(*) > 10
order by lastupdated desc
```

It looks like 'having' can only be used in select statments though:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

So you may need to have your update's where clause include a select statement:

```
update members_eligibile
   set hsd=1 
  from teams 
 where teams.memid=members_eligible.memid 
   and (teams.role = 'HSD' OR teams.role = 'SD')  
   and teams.movement = 'Cursillo' 
   and members_eligible.memid IN
   (SELECT members_eligible.memid from members_eligible where teams.memid=members_eligible.memid  having count(teams.role) > 1);
```

You will have to adjust the select statement, I haven't tested it

Comment: I am new at this MySql stuff and learning how to use the commands.  This suggestion, which I found when I did a search, is good, but I don't know how to incorporate it into what I need to Accomplish.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like having can only be used with select: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx Try an update with a select subquery, ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005+

```
UPDATE x
SET x.hsd = 1
FROM (SELECT e.hsd, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.role) AS cnt
      FROM teams t JOIN members_eligibile e ON t.memid = e.memid
      WHERE (t.role = 'HSD' OR t.role = 'SD') AND t.movement = 'Cursillo') x
WHERE x.cnt > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  I copied this into editor for MySQL and I can't get it to run.  Might be some syntax difference between SQL Server 2005+ and MySql.  It did give me a place to study and learn though so I'll keep playing with it to see if I can figure it out.