# Use COUNT(*) AS `COUNT` in MYSQL Where Clause

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to find, count and report all instances of duplicates entries in a column. Any idea how to do that similar to my attempt below.

```
SELECT `Id`, COUNT(*) AS `COUNT`
FROM `testproductdata`
WHERE `COUNT` > 1
GROUP BY `Id`
ORDER BY `COUNT` DESC;
```

I am getting a 1054 error: Unknown column `COUNT` in where clause.

Comment: Use GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT, a self-join, or a nested select.

Comment: That works, can you submit it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301793/mysql-using-count-in-the-where-clause?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `HAVING` over `WHERE` with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT `Id`, COUNT(*) AS `COUNT`
FROM `testproductdata`
GROUP BY `Id`
HAVING  `COUNT` > 1
ORDER BY `COUNT` DESC;
```

And I suggest to use relevant name for expression on `count(*)` as `total_count` than `COUNT`.

Change query as below:

```
SELECT `Id`, COUNT(*) AS `total_count`
FROM `testproductdata`
GROUP BY `Id`
HAVING  `total_count` > 1
ORDER BY `total_count` DESC;
```

Comment: @EricImprint Hmm, another MySQL oddity (or at least difference) strikes me.

Comment: It works. Better practice is not to use [*Reserved words*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `count` as identifiers, though it is an acceptable with no *back ticks*

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `DISTINCT` to the query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT `Id`, (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM `testproductdata` WHERE `Id`=`Id`) `count`
FROM `testproductdata`
GROUP BY `Id`
HAVING `count` > 1
)
ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

Comment: I am getting a 1054 error: Unknown column COUNT in where clause.

Comment: Why not ?.  Oh... hahaha... i see XD ---  need to rename the field... also, don't use `AS` ...  just space.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Not yet. "In general, clauses used must be given in exactly the order shown in the syntax description. For example, a HAVING clause must come after any GROUP BY clause and before any ORDER BY clause." see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should change the where for a having, this should work:

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(1) AS count
FROM testproductdata
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
select * from 
(SELECT `Id`, COUNT(*) AS `c`
FROM `testproductdata`
group by `Id`)
WHERE `c` > 1
ORDER BY `c` DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT `Id`, COUNT(*) AS `c`
FROM `testproductdata`
group by `Id`
having `c` > 1
ORDER BY `c` DESC;
```