# MySQL: WHERE COUNT(*) = 0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all the customer_id's where no rows from have been found, for example:

`SELECT customer_id FROM transaction WHERE count(*) = '0'`

I have tried this aswell:

`SELECT customer_id, count(*) as total_rows FROM transaction WHERE total_rows='0'`

But I get the error that total_rows is not a column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Using COUNT(\*) in the WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301793/mysql-using-count-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: in query processing this is the logical order `From`>`where` since where is evaluated prior to select you get the error `that total_rows is not a column`

Comment: Both queries does not make sense, could you provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Check out `HAVING` clause ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html ). But I have to say, your query doesn't look logical. If you have no entries in table, than you don't have any `customer_id` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to think about it in a bit of a different way: "how do I get a list of all customers who have no transaction history?"

Simple! You get a list of all of the customers, join it against their transactions and filter out any customers who have a non-empty list of transactions. Or, in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    customer.customer_id 
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN transaction
    ON transaction.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE
    transaction.transaction_id IS NULL
```

---

Note that you cannot simply use the `transaction` table like you're attempting. It is not a complete list of `customer_id` but rather it contains only IDs of customers who have an order.

Instead of operating on `transaction` and finding customers with no transactions (which you literally cannot do), you must find all customers and then filter by those who have no transactions. Similar concept, just opposite order.