# How to use COUNT in IF statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

`Travel(id, title, date, travelMethod)` with `id` as the primary key.

I need to get a list of all `id`s that have travelled using the bus 3 times. That's to say, if they rode the bus three times, they would be in this table 3 times.

I think it's something like

```
SELECT id FROM Travel WHERE (something here with count(*))
```

but I'm not really sure how to do this, I am new at SQL. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: additional info.

I said `id` is unique, but that is false for this table. Here is some sample data:

[image: sample data]

So I need the `ids` of all users from table who took the bus 3 times.

Comment: In your table `id` is the primary key . So that will be unique for all records in your table. You can get all the `ids where travelMethod = 'bus' `

Comment: If `id` is the primary key each `id` is in the table exactly once only, suggest you show us some actual sample data and results you are expecting,

Comment: An image of sample data is useless, as it can't be copied and pasted to create a test table. Please post the sample data in the form of DDL and DML that can be copied, pasted and executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple aggregate will give you the required IDs:

```
select Id
from Travel
where travelMethod='Bus'
group by Id
having count(*)=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using having count(*)

```
   select Id  from Travel  where travelMethod='Bus'
        group by Id having count(*) =3 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
SELECT id FROM Travel GROUP BY id HAVING (something here with count(*))
```

reference : [MYSQL using count in the where clouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301793/mysql-using-count-in-the-where-clause)